# GPO copy file task does not work into roaming folder

Tags: group-policy, copy

We created a GPO task to copy a file from our share(`\\SRV01\Datastore\Team\Shared\TEST_Addin.xlam`) to the user's roaming folder (`%AppData%\Microsoft\AddIns\TEST_Addin.xlam`). On this shared location everyone has access and the GPO is enabled in a test client (checked by `gpresult /r`). But the file does not appear. How can I check what went wrong?

Comment: What group policy settings are you using to copy the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I recommend troubleshooting group policy using event logs.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749336(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

@Chris: Thanks. I saw that in the event viewer it was a permission issue. So i changed to  use local rights (because it's the `%appdata%` folder) and now it works!